# Why doesn't my Samsung cable charge?

Tags: usb, charging

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4. It has it's own charger with a detachable cable, able to go to USB ports. [This one](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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) to be exact, it works perfectly. I also have a Surface pro 3 and [it's charger](http://images.anandtech.com/reviews/tablets/microsoft/SurfacePro3/DSC_5693.jpg). As can be seen from the picture, it has a USB port for charging, it also works. It's when I combine my Surface charger and my Samsung cable, that I get a problem. The lightning icon appears on my phone, but it's not really charging at all. Changing the cable with my other cables fixes it.

Comment: It might be that Samsung is shipped with a non-standard proprietary cable design in order to make you buy the overpriced original.

Answer (score 0):

The Power which your Phone consumes outway the Power a USB Port can supply.
This problem is often faced when using an Powerbank.

Cause could be an old Battery which lifetime is coming to a close, but thats anyones guess.
I would buy myself a charger that goes in to the Wall socket. Way more convinient.
For example, it would take 5h for my Nexus 5 to fully recharge from USB and only 2 hours from the wall Socket directly.

Comment: Why do you think it out-ways the power a USB Port supplies? I've clearly stated that just switching the cable fixes everything. Also this same cable works with the original charger, so it's their combination, not an individual part.